# Underscore Js zip method

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

We need to merge two arrays to each other and get a new array. By doing this we have used Underscore Js zip method. But this method not merge the null values. In a new array we need null values. How we merge null values?

```js
var a = [],
  b = [];

a.push(2, 5, 4, null, 4, 8, 7, null, 2, 5, 7);
b.push(12, 15, 14, null, 4, 8, null, 8, 2, 5, 7);

var c = _.zip(a, b);
window.alert(c);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Null literally represents the absence of a value, is it possible to use 0 instead?

Comment: Your code is doing what you want. Use `console.log()` and you'll see the nulls.

Comment: When `null` is converted to a string by `alert()`, it's converted to an empty string.

Comment: We have a financial application, 0 is a valid value in financial application. Actually we bind this array to highchart and highchart have a property connectNulls. By using this property our chart line is not break. Is there any other way to join two arrays like zip method?

Comment: @Barmar is correct. The code is doing exactly as you ask. Check in a debugger and you will see null values.

Answer (score 0):

Null is never considered as a value, it is not problem of underscore js. It is characteristic of javascript itself. (not only js, it holds same for almost all languages)
hence you get empty value. try using `alert(a)` i.e only for variable `a`, you will get same result. if u explicitly need `null` on your `alert()`, give it as string value :`"null"`. hope it helps.